# Check for multiple object properties in AppleScript

Tags: applescript, reminders

I wrote an AppleScript that shall check existing reminders in the Reminders app for their name. If a reminder with the given name (Erinnerung) does not exist one shall be created.

But the following code does check the uncompleted reminders only:

```
tell application "Reminders"
    if exists (reminders whose name is Erinnerung) then
    else
        set newremin to make new reminder
        set name of newremin to Erinnerung
    end if
end tell
```

So I tried to check for the name and the completion status at once:

```
tell application "Reminders"
    if exists (reminders with properties {name:Erinnerung, completed:true}) then
    else
        set newremin to make new reminder
        set name of newremin to Erinnerung
    end if
end tell
```

But then I'm getting **an error**:

> "„properties:true“ kann nicht diesem „reminders“ folgen."
>   ("„properties:true“ can not follow this „reminders“")

Why does the Reminders app check for uncompleted reminders only? And why can't I check for two properties at once? Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To filter objects by one or more properties filter the array and count the elements of the result.

One property (I changed the variable `Erinnerung` to a literal string)

```
tell application "Reminders"
    set erinnerungen to reminders whose name is "Erinnerung"
    if (count erinnerungen) is 0 then
        set newremin to make new reminder
        set name of newremin to "Erinnerung"
    end if
end tell
```

Two properties

```
tell application "Reminders"
    set erinnerungen to reminders whose name is "Erinnerung" and completed is true
    if (count erinnerungen) is 0 then
        set newremin to make new reminder
        set name of newremin to "Erinnerung"
    end if
end tell
```

If you want to check an object which can be referenced by name you can also use this

```
tell application "Reminders"
    if not (exists reminder "Erinnerung") then
        set newremin to make new reminder
        set name of newremin to "Erinnerung"
    end if
end tell
```